# integral of absolute value of a function.

Tags: integration

The problem is as following:
straight lines are drawn joining every point on $y=\sqrt{3}x\sin{x}$ to the origin. what fraction of the x-y plane is occupied by these lines.

My solution is:

I observe that the limit of $y=\sqrt{3}x\sin{x}$ is oscillating between positive and negative. So the graph of the function cross x-axis infinitely many times as $x$ goes to infinity. What the problem ask is actually to compute the fraction of the integral of absolute value of the funciton to the area of the $xy$-plane. Since $y=\sqrt{3}x\sin{x}$ is even function, it is enough to consider right half of $xy$-plane. I compute the integral of absolute value of $y=\sqrt{3}x\sin{x}$ on the right half plane by spliting the right half $xy$-plane by $k\pi$'s, where $k$ represents an integer range from $0$ to infinity.

$\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\sqrt{3}x\sin{x} dx|}{2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\pi\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{x}}$

After computation, the result on the top of the fraction is $\sqrt{3}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(2k+1)\pi$ and the result on the bottom of the fraction is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(2n\pi\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{x})$.

Hence the fraction is result of the fraction is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt{3}(n+1)^2}{2n{\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{x}}}$, which is just to compute the limit of the expression $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sqrt{3}(x+1)^2}{2x^2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

But the place I find this question, it is with an answer that is $\frac{2}{3}$.

So I am wondering if these are any mistakes of my solution? or I am correct and the answer I found is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you complicated your life.

[image]

Here is the graph of $\sqrt{3}x\sin(x)$.

Since $|\sin(x)|<1$ then $-\sqrt{3}x\le f(x)\le\sqrt{3}x$ and the set of lines joining every point of the curve to the origin is just the part of the plane between these two straight lines (imagine the blue part, all filled with blue).

Since this region is infinite as well as the plane, I guess the ratio is calculated by evaluating the angular filling.

The angle of $y=\pm\sqrt{3}x$ are $\pm 60°$ so the overall angular load factor is $\dfrac{4\times60°}{360°}=\dfrac 23$

Comment: I agree with you. But the graph is not easy to draw. Without knowing how the graph look like, I am wondering how do you get the answer? what is your idea and clue?

Comment: The idea is $\sin$ is continuous so it takes all values between $-1$ and $+1$ thus $ax\sin(x)$ is stuck between $-ax$ and $+ax$.

Comment: great~ got it. Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 1):

Checking your answer without using calculus:
Since $\sin x$ varies continuously from its minimum, $-1$, to its maximum, $1$, the drawn rays have slopes from $-\sqrt{3}$ to $\sqrt{3}$.  These rays are drawn both to the left and the right of the origin.  The ray with slope $\sqrt{3}$ to the right of the origin makes an angle of $\pi/3$ with the positive $x$-axis.  The ray with slope $-\sqrt{3}$ likewise makes an angle of $\pi / 3$.  To the left of the origin, the same is obtained.  This means the region(s) covered by rays fill $4 \cdot \frac{\pi}{3}$.  Thus, they cover $\frac{4 \pi /3}{2 \pi} = \frac{4}{6} = \frac{2}{3}$ of the plane.

Your solution has a few defects.

- You do not include the region to the left of the origin.
- When you integrate $\sqrt{3} x \sin x$, you are finding the area covered by lines from the point on the graph extending vertically to the $x$-axis, *not* from the point on the graph to the origin.
- Your denominator is nonsense.  It says: first find $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x = \infty$, then multiply that $\pi$, yielding $\infty$, then sum that for $k=0$ to $\infty$, obtaining $\infty$, finally, multiply by $2$, producing $\infty$.
- If you were to use this method, your denominator should be a rectangle that grows in both $x$- *and* $y$-directions with $k$.

If we were going to attack the question you answered (which is not the given question), we would have tried something like
$$  \lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\int_{-M}^M \; | \sqrt{3} x \sin x |  \,\mathrm{d}x}{(2M)(2 \sqrt{3} M)}  \text{.}  $$
This version

- Includes the part of the plane to the left of the origin.
- Integrates the length of each line segment, rather than trying to split the range of integration into pieces where the line segments are all either positively directed or negatively directed.
- Finds the part of the plane covered over the range $x \in [-M,M]$, divided by the part of the plane $[-M,M] \times [-\sqrt{3} M, \sqrt{3} M]$, the rectangle bounding the envelope of the function.
- Puts the limit in a place where it can work for us, and shows that we are looking at the *sequence* of fractions of bounding rectangles covered by vertical lines from the graph of the function to the $x$-axis.

That integral is a little tricky.  If we split into regions bounded by integer multiples of $\pi$, we get 
$$  \int_{k \pi}^{(k+1)\pi} \; \sqrt{3} x \sin x \, \mathrm{d} x = (-1)^k \sqrt{3}\pi|2k+1|  \text{.}  $$
When $k$ is even, these contributions are positive, and when $k$ is odd, negative, so we can correct the signs (to implement the absolute value) by dropping the "$(-1)^k$".  Since we are now breaking the $x$-axis up into $pi$ wide pieces, we should adjust the terms in the denominator to do so as well.  Making these replacements, we obtain \begin{align*}
  \lim_{\substack{M \rightarrow \infty\\M \in \mathbb{Z}}} & \frac{\sum_{k=-M}^{M} \sqrt{3} \pi |2k+1|}{(2 \pi M)(2 \sqrt{3} \pi M)}  \\
    &= \lim_{\substack{M \rightarrow \infty\\M \in \mathbb{Z}}} \frac{\sqrt{3}\pi(2M^2 + 2M + 1)}{(2 \pi M)(2 \sqrt{3} \pi M)}  \\
    &= \frac{1}{2\pi}  \text{.}
\end{align*}

This is substantially smaller than $\frac{2}{3}$ because only counting the area between the graph of the function and the $x$-axis captures substantially less area than counting the area covered by rays from the origin to the points of the graph.

Comment: I do not understand why you choose $[-M,M]\times[-\sqrt{3}M,\sqrt{3}M]$, as the rectangle instead of other coefficient. e.g. $2$, $3$, $\sqrt{5}$ or some number else? I think I miss some knowledge about this.....I just aware  that it is about the rate of change of $M$ and the rate of change of the rectangle....

Comment: Which rectangle?  The rectangle with corners at $(\pm M, \pm \sqrt{3} M)$, because rectangles with these corners exactly "sweep up" the graph along their left and right edges.  If the $y$-coordinates are smaller, the graph extends above and below the rectangles, if larger, the rectangles contain an unreachable margin along the top and bottom edges.  Why $\pm\sqrt{3}$?  Because those are the slopes of the lines bounding the top and bottom of the graph of the function.

Comment: The function is an even function. So I think it is enough to compute the integral of right half of the plane. Double the result, I will get the whole integral. I double checked. There is a little bit difference in the process between my computation for the top of the fraction and yours. The difference will not effect the result.

Comment: What is the reason you use the slopes of the lines bounding the top and bottom of the graph of the funciton? And the function you refer to is the original function I guess?

Comment: @HuiYILU : So when, in your answer did this doubling occur?  It's not visible in any of your displayed equations, nor do you mention it in your text.

Comment: @HuiYILU : The only function in sight is $\sqrt{3} x \sin x$.  The analogy (and the right way to do this problem) is in polar coordinates.  We take the limit as the included radius increases of the ratio of the included area to the total area.  For each choice of radius we keep only the part of the plane that is covered by the function and the part of the plane that is bounded by the radius.  With rectangles, it is easy to keep the horizontal extent synchronized; the vertical extent covered by the function is bounded by the lines of slopes $\pm \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: This question is asking the ratio only. So I do not need to double. I just half the bottom of the fraction to half plane.

Comment: For your reason about the boundary rectangle, I just feel a little bit vague....I am not able to be comfirmed by your reasoning.....

Comment: @HuiYILU : Your denominator is an unintelligibly overcomplicated way to write $\infty$.  It has a factor of $2$ in it, so it appears to be counting area on both sides of the origin.  Or maybe it's trying to count area above and below the $x$-axis.  Who can tell?

Comment: I do try to use polar coordinate before using regular coordinate.....but the computation is too complicated. I do get the integral, but there are lot of "not defined" problem when I substitute the values...

Comment: @HuiYILU : The entire method, using an integral of the function to compute the area *in the stated problem*, is misguided, so some uneasiness may come from there.  However, you are free to look at the $\lim_{\substack{M_1 \rightarrow \infty, M_2 \rightarrow \infty \\ N_1 \rightarrow \infty, N_2 \rightarrow\infty}}$ of the covered area in the in the rectangle $[M_1, M_2] \times [N_1, N_2]$.  Of course, this limit doesn't exist, so to get a number at all one has to introduce relations among the bounds.

Comment: I guess maybe you misunderstand what I ask? I did not ask for the reason why choose the rectangle way to found the ratio. I just not sure how the rectangle method works.

Comment: @HuiYILU : I recommend you draw the picture.

Comment: Draw picture still now answer my question....more specifically, which theorems, axioms or corollaries you are using to reasoning....? I think to prove something is true in math, we need to use theorems and etc...

Comment: @HuiYILU : You tell me which theorems, axioms, or corollaries led you to write the denominator "$2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\pi\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{x}$", because that denominator does not capture any feature of the problem or its solution.  If you cannot clearly articulate what you are going to calculate from the problem description/diagram, then no amount of formalism will rescue you.

Comment: Actually this step I do not know which theorem to use. That is why I am not sure about I am correct or not.....I think the using of rectangle way should have some theorem supporting it. It seems related to the rate of change of M.

Comment: @erics   I finally got the answer: the limit do not exist. For reasoning, please have a look at the answer I posted below.

Answer (score -1):

Let me explain myself in another way by answering a question: ***What fraction of $xy$-plane occupied by the area bounded by $|\sqrt{3}x\sin{x}|$ and the $x$-axis?***

After computing the integral of $|\sqrt{3}x\sin{x}|$ as what I did in my first post, the solution leads to compute the limit of 
$\frac{\sqrt{3}\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}(M+1)^2}{2\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}N^2}$
 where both top and bottom are discrete functions.

For this question, I think we can choose any function, to compute the area of the $xy$-plane ( as long as this function is able to get the area. e.g we can choose either discrete or continuous function). But for this specific problem, we'd better to use discrete function, because the top of the fraction is discrete. In order to use the quotient rule for limit, we require that both top and bottom of the quotient to have the same property (both discrete or both continuous).

How can we use the quotient rule to calculate limit of a function with multiple variables? This arises to same problem as to compute the limit:
$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0, y\rightarrow 0}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$
We can solve this question by change the Cartesian coordinate to polar coordinate. But for the question here, this technique is not applicable.

I compute the limit of this quotient with different relation between $M$ and $N$. For example use linear relation $N=\sqrt{3}M$ or $N=M^2$. We get different answer.

**Conclusion: The limit of this quotient do not exist. the theorem I use is that a function can only have one limit if its limit exists.**

**Hence, the solution of this question does not exist.**

We should not change different variables directly to the same variables. As this changes, we narrow our computation to a fix relation between two variables. Actually, if not specifically mentioned, there will be no relation between variables. in this question, there is no extra conditions mentioned to restrict the variable for the functions on the top of the quotient and on the bottom of the quotient to only one relation: $M=\sqrt{3}N$. We should not add a relation ourselves, which may cause incorrect judgement for the existence of the limit.

Comment: This is not a correct analysis of the given problem "straight lines are drawn joining every point on $y=\sqrt{3}x\sin{x}$ to the origin".  Why do you continue to believe that drawing lines to the origin is the same as drawing lines vertically to the $x$-axis?

Comment: @erics I did not talk about the solution of this question. I just talk about the solution for solving the limit of the quotient. And answer myself the question I asked you that why we should use rectangle method.